# Nvidia scraper with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, nvidia

Good afternoon,
I try to scrape nvidia's api link to get stock status (for testing) but it doesn't print the last data (`productPrice`).
Here is my code :

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.nvidia.partners/edge/product/search?page=1&limit=9&locale=fr-fr&category=GPU&gpu=RTX%203090,RTX%203080%20Ti,RTX%203080,RTX%203070%20Ti,RTX%203070,RTX%203060%20Ti,RTX%203060&gpu_filter=RTX%203090~12,RTX%203080%20Ti~7,RTX%203080~16,RTX%203070%20Ti~3,RTX%203070~18,RTX%203060%20Ti~8,RTX%203060~2'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for p in data["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"]:
    print("{:<50} {}".format(p["productTitle"],p["productAvailable"], p["productPrice"]))
```

I have this (so i haven't the price):

```
NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3080                            False
NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3070                            False
NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3060 Ti                         False
NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3070 Ti                         False
NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3080 Ti                         False
Gigabyte GeForce RTX 3060 EAGLE OC 12G             False
Palit NE63060019K9-190AD graphics card             False
PNY VCG306012DFXPPB graphics card                  False
Palit NE63060T19K9-190AD graphics card             False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use  `.format` in python every `{}` present a value so in order to add `productPrice` you need to do this :

```
print("{:<50} {}  {}".format(p["productTitle"],p["productAvailable"], p["productPrice"]))
```

Comment: okay thanks, I will check that.